# MAC Catalina Upgrade error The disk doesn't use the GUID partition

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos, catalina

I have this problem  when I want to upgrade my MACOS from Yosemit to Catalina

[image]
My pc specs are as fallow:

[image: png]

When i'm going to volume I can't select anything 
[image]

And if I go to erase, the same problem happens

[image]

When I diskutil list & diskutil cs list

```
ADMINs-MBP-2:~ ADMIN$ diskutil list & diskutil cs list
[1] 641
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
ADMINs-MBP-2:~ ADMIN$ /dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                251.0 GB   disk0s1

[1]+  Done                    diskutil list
ADMINs-MBP-2:~ ADMIN$
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t erase the drive and then install? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496 also two && will make the output cleaner, but doesn’t affect the good detail it provides. +1

Comment: "When i'm going to volume I can't select anything" - it looks like you can select "Current".  Is that not the case?  Change that to 1 Partition and "Options..." should become active / clickable.